# Real time output in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

In my python code having:

```
print "Hello"
time.sleep(20)
print "world"
```

I am expecting output as

```
Hello
```

and then after 20 seconds

```
world
```

But `Hello` and `world` are printing simultaneously in the console.

Comment: By "at the same time", do you mean without any delay at all, or are they both delayed together? Also, please provide an exact and complete example (this is not a complete example, because it's missing an `import`), and verify that that example reproduces the issue.

Comment: Is time.sleep() expecting seconds or milliseconds?

Comment: Maybe you have not imported time, so instead of waiting 20 seconds there is a NameError.

Comment: @Patashu Then why would it ever print "world" at all? Why doesn't it error out at the call to `time.sleep(20)` with a `NameError`? I don't think that's the problem.

Comment: python code imported with sys,os and time module.time.sleep(20) it is in 20 seconds.First am expecting "Hello" and after 20 seconds "world" in the console.

Answer (score 5):

`print` operator effectively uses `sys.stdout` stream for output which is buffered.
For real-time output you'll want to use `sys.stderr` stream which is not buffered:

```
import sys, time
sys.stderr.write("Hello ")
time.sleep(20)
sys.stderr.write("world\n")
```

Alternatively, you can flush stream buffer manually by calling `sys.stdout.flush()` each time you want to get output but I suggest you not to do it in such way unless you know what you're doing.

For more details there is an [article in Wikipedia on standard streams (stdin, stdout and stderr)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams).

Answer (score 1):

Your code works in my computer. You can try to flush the stdout directly after printing `hello`

```
import sys
sys.stdout.flush()
```

Comment: My code has so many print commands.So I have to give "sys.stdout.flush()" after every print command.Is there any other way ??

Answer (score -1):

Make sure you've imported the time library from python, and try it on both versions of python to see if you can experience the same error. I've tried it on my end and it works.

Comment: It would throw an error when trying to run `time.sleep()` if it was not imported.